# What are allogametes? please explain

Tags: cell-biology, botany, zoology, gamete

Allo means different or unrelated I guess.Please clear me the meaning with some examples.

Comment: Where did you read the term allogamete? I dont think I've ever encountered this term. I would guess it applies to species that have a double nucleus such as many fungi species.

Comment: Here are a few notes on how to ask a question: 1) When asking for a definition, please provide the context in which you found the word to be defined 2) writing `please explain` in the title is useless 3) Add a space after the `.` at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I vote to close as unclear until your provided where you encountered this term.

Comment: @Remi.b I think you are being unnecessarily harsh. This is an example of a poorly asked question that leads to an interesting and informative answer.

Comment: @AMR I think it is still unclear whether the OP was meaning `allogamy` or `allogamete`. Simple edits would much improve the clarity of the question. Good answer though (+1)

Comment: I vote to close as it shows *absolutely* no research effort.

Comment: @rg255 Have you actually tried to research "allogametes?" Google scholar has 2 hits, one being a Science article from 1911. Google comes back with related hits, but none that specifically mention "allogametes." The OPs profile says that they are from India. If they are not well versed in science writing in English, then it may have been difficult to evaluate what they were seeing when not finding an exact hit. 1911 science writing would be difficult for most American science students not familiar with reading texts from the turn of the last century.

Comment: It's a poorly formulated question that would benefit greatly if the user made greater research effort, in my opinion

Comment: And....the OP should have said something by now. We've been discussing the meaning of its question for 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

You may be getting confused with the term **[Allogamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allogamy)**.

**Humans** most higher animals are allogamous, which means that the ovum from one organism is fertilized by spermatozoa of a different organisms.

If you read the term allogametes somewhere, then the reference likely means spermatozoa from one organism of a species and ova from another organism of the same species. There were two references on Google Scholar to allogametes. This reference is in Science from 1911, no that is not a typo. 
[Dimorphism of the Gametes of Œnothera](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1638375?seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents) by Walter T. Swingle.

Species that have hermaphrodites, such as nematodes and other types of worms can be **autogamous**, meaning that the organism produces both the ova and spermatozoa and self-fertilize. In this case the offspring of this organism are clones of the hermaphrodite, which can come in handy in genetics experiments. Basically you are doing a self-cross.

Many of these species can also be allogamous. In the case of the nematode you usually have the Hermaphrodite, which is XX and the male which is XO. The male only produces spermatozoa and when mating with the hermaphrodite, their sperm takes precedence over that of the hermaphrodite. This is likely due to a last in first out situation in the spermatheca of the hermaphrodite. Sperm develops in the hermaphrodite first and are deposited in the spermatheca, then the ova form. If a male mates with the hermaphrodite, 'his' sperm is deposited in the spermatheca of the hermaphrodite and then as the ova pass the spermatheca on their way to the vulva they are fertilized by the sperm.

**Edit**

[The Urologic and Cutaneous Review: Technical supplement, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=RxowAQAAMAAJ&pg=PT262&lpg=PT262&dq=allogametes&source=bl&ots=b3RLpLvmQh&sig=sYQ49lXTgs8hSsjdGM9YaE-niaY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9oMrVo_rJAhWI5SYKHQO9AewQ6AEIMzAG#v=onepage&q=allogametes&f=false) from 1914 on a section on the origin of sexual reproduction (The Origin of Amphigony), also makes mention of the term "allogametes" in reference to protist cells which are able to differentiate and fuse and then divide asexually after the fusion even. The key in this text is made from differentiated cells, allogametes, or similar cells, isogametes, that are capable of fusing and producing a new cell capable of cell division.

Comment: It is also possible that the OP is referring to allopolyploids, in which case the gametes come from two different species with different genomes that produce an offspring that can lead to a new species. This is seen in plant breeding. If OP responds with clarification I will attempt to expand on that.